# Draw a contour on the leaf to calculate the area using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to draw a contour on the leaf to calculate the area of the leaf using OpenCV but `cv2.findContours()` does not draw a contour around the leaf but the other regions.

**My Code**

```
def Contours_Detection(image_path):
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.resize(img,(500,500), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)  
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    
    # store the a-channel        
    a_channel = lab[:,:,1]
    
    # Automate threshold using Otsu method        
    th = cv2.threshold(a_channel,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    
    # Mask the result with the original image        
    masked = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = th)
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(masked, 7)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    binary = cv2.threshold(gray,125, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    MORPH_close = cv2.morphologyEx(binary, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=2)
    result = 255 - MORPH_close
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(result, mode=cv2.RETR_LIST, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    Num_of_contour = len(contours)
    image_copy = image.copy()
    spot_on_org_img = cv2.drawContours(image_copy, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
    black_img = np.zeros(image.shape)
    
    # draw the contours on the black image        
    spot_on_black_img = cv2.drawContours(black_img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
    return spot_on_black_img

image_path = '/content/IMG_3407.jpg'
spot_on_black_img = Contours_Detection(image_path)
cv2_imshow(spot_on_black_img)
```

**Input Image**

[image: input image]

**Output Image**

[image: output image]

Comment: Can you fix iformat ndentation?

Comment: Post your image to some free hosting service and put the URL in your question or a comment.

Comment: Does your th threshold image show the leaf as white on black background or black on white background. Be sure it is the former.

Comment: In addition to checking your threshold image for polarity, try using mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL when finding contours

Comment: I edited this question into a better shape, but it's still lacking a proper MCVE -- your code example lacks relevant imports, and the function `cv2_imshow` is not defined. Please [edit] your question and fix that. | That said, you've provided a useful input and almost-complete code. Good job, that's orders of magnitude better than what most new users manage. :)

Comment: Anyway, right now it seems your definition of a (grass?) leaf is just "something that is sort of green". Obviously that's not enough, so you will need to do some further processing. What are some other properties of a grass leaf that you can observe from that image? | (Two things I can see there -- the leaf has almost straight edges, and the leaf is in focus but the other stuff is not)